# How to write code to sqlite straight from r markdown

Tags: r, sqlite, r-markdown

I have setup a connection using

````
```{r defineconnection}
my_connection <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),"/cloud/project/week_04/bibitor.db")
```
````

Next I wrote in a table to the database

````
```{r writebacktodb}
RSQLite::dbWriteTable(my_connection,"VendorInvoicesDec",VendorInvoicesDec,overwrite=TRUE)
```
````

I am now trying to select a column from that table using

````
```{sql, connection=my_connection}
SELECT VendorName
FROM VendorInvoicesDec ;
```
````

with the connection "{sql, connection=my_connection}" but I keep getting

> SELECT VendorName
> Error: unexpected symbol in "SELECT VendorName"
> FROM VendorInvoicesDec ;
> Error: unexpected symbol in "FROM VendorInvoicesDec"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what actually happens. Errors? Undesired results? Nothing? *It's not working* is not a helpful description.

Comment: @Parfait Yh you're right, I have done so now.

Comment: I can't precisely figure out youur issue. It seems as if this SQL chunk is running under R and not SQL. Be sure this chunk is not embedded inside an R chunk. Check triple backticks are placed correctly. Be sure that you are running chunks inside an .Rmd not .R script under RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised the code was working inline and only showed an error in the console. I always set the output to chunk in console so I didn't notice it before.